# How to undeploy multiple WARs with single HTTP management API query in WildFly?

Tags: http, wildfly, war, wildfly-10, undeploy

I undeploy a WAR using HTTP management API of Wildfly 10 the following way:

```
curl --digest -u admin:admin -L -H 'Content-Type: application/json'        \
      -d '{"address":[{"deployment":"my-war.war"}],"operation":"remove"}'  \
      http://localhost:9990/management
```

How to undeploy more than one WAR using one Wildfly HTTP management API request?

I can't find the solution in official docs:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/WFLY10/The+HTTP+management+API
https://docs.jboss.org/author/WFLY10/Application+deployment

I'm looking for JSON that can undeploy multiple WARs.
I've tried some ways with JSON arrays, but to no avail. Some of them result in 500 - Internal Server Error, others fail with WFLYCTL0030 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in the [EAP 6.4 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/sect-deploy_with_the_http_api#Deploy_an_application_using_the_HTTP_API)

```
curl --digest -L -D - http://localhost:9990/management --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
   "operation":"composite",
   "address":[  
   ],
   "steps":[
      {
         "operation":"undeploy",
         "address":{
            "deployment":"my-war.war"
         }
      },
      {
         "operation":"remove",
         "address":{
            "deployment":"my-war.war"
         }
      },
      {
         "operation":"undeploy",
         "address":{  
            "deployment":"my-second-war.war"
         }
      },
      {
         "operation":"remove",
         "address":{
            "deployment":"my-second-war.war"
         }
      }
   ],
   "json.pretty":1
}' -u admin:admin
```

Comment: It works fine. Thanks.
Though I've found such a composite operation fails with WFLYCTL0062 code and does nothing if one of its steps fails.
That might be a reason not to use that approach but simply invoke a separate request for each WAR deployed. At least I decided not to use it due to the issue discovered.